# how to check true lat/long in polygon in mysql

Tags: mysql, polygon, spatial

this query not result:

```
select *
from provinces
 where ST_Contains(GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',51.4, ' ', 37.2,')'),4326),polygon)
```

Comment: Can you try this: `SELECT * from provinces where ST_CONTAINS(ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYGON((47 -67, 47 -123, 21 -78, 47 -67)'), point(51.4, 37.2)))`

Comment: this query dose not execute and has error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ea.entity_id,ea.latitude, ea.longitude ,c.name
from entity_addresses  as ea
inner join cities as c on  ST_CONTAINS(c.polygon, 
               ST_GeomFromText(ST_AsText(point(ea.longitude, ea.latitude)), 
4326))
```